# Laravel 5.5 Shared hosting changing from /public to /public_html - partially working

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5.5, public-html

I have read through a thread on [Laracasts thread] (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5?page=2) but not sure of the current right solution especially for Laravel 5.5 ? (note: i do not have access to change any config server side apart from selecting which Php version to use - and a handful ssh commands [with limited directories i can access] ).

My case: using shared hosting, so my public directory is

`/home/{mycomputer generated user}/public_html/`

Initially I uploaded Laravel directory into public_html folder . The system worked with the quirks of having the URL `www.mydomain.xyz/public/` as the URL to root.

Then I tried this approach of modifying the path:

1. Moved all files out of the `public_html` folder to have the same level as `public_html` folder.

So the folders (in my previously laravel folder) reside here:

`/home/{mycomputer generated user}/`

2. Copied the content of `/public` into `/public_html`
3. Edited the `index.php` content of `/public_html`

FROM: 
`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

TO: 
`require '/home/{my user}/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once '/home/{my user}/bootstrap/app.php';`

And now my main page loaded fine (welcome view)  as stated in my web.php route file

`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`

===================================================================

MY ISSUE:

However, any other routes would fail

"Not Found

The requested URL `/{legitimate route}` was not found on this server"

Any other steps that i needed to do?

I tried:
1. loading a simple jpg file stored in public_html folder, and that worked fine (mydomain.xyz/test.jpg )

2. changed the route for root to return invalid view, that threw a Laravel error

`Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('test');
    });`

`"InvalidArgumentException
View [test] not found."`

3. Tried using closures (instead of using controllers) to return a legit view - did not work

`Route::get('/main', function () {
    return view('tempview.main');
});`

What did i miss? .htaccess changes? another place where i need to change the public path?

Answer (score 2):

I am answering depend on your trying:

Step 1. copy index.php and .htaccess from public to public_html that means into root folder.

Step 2. modify the index.php into public_html folder

```
From: require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

To: require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

And

```
From: $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

To: $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```